# My "a" tag is not stretching the full height of my "img"

Tags: html, css

I was remaking the Kurzgesagt home page for a project and I wanted to make my `a` tag stretch the full height of my `img`. The `a` tag wraps the `img` in the HTML.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://kurzgesagt.org/work/bitdefender/">
  <img src="images/happyDevices.png">
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
  height: auto;
}

img {
  width: 24.8%;
  height: 24.8%;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Tag is fully stretched. Can you please explain what do you want to implement ?

Comment: Your image can't scretch if it's parent div/tag doesn't have a height, as `height: auto` doesn't set a height for the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

You can either try setting the anchor tag a width for the image and set a display of inline-block like so:

```
a {
    width: 24.8%;
    display: inline-block;
}

img {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Provided a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/h2qkfc4e/

Answer (score 0):

Assign `display: block;` to the image:

```css
a {
  height: auto;
}

img {
  width: 24.8%;
  height: 24.8%;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://kurzgesagt.org/work/bitdefender/">
  <img src="images/happyDevices.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Yeah but I want it to display inline-block

Answer (score 0):

You can also use max-width=100%, max-height=100%